# React createPortal does not add element to DOM without any errors

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dom, react-portal

I am trying to create a dynamic modal with React and MaterialUI.

Currently adding them like this:

```
// Confirm.js
import { WarningAmber } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { LoadingButton } from '@mui/lab'
import { Button, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle } from '@mui/material'
import { t } from 'i18next'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Confirm({ open, setOpen, title, message, onConfirm, onCancel = () => null }) {
  const [saving, setSaving] = useState(false)

  function handleCancel() {
    onCancel()
    setOpen(false)
  }

  function handleConfirm() {
    setSaving(true)
    onConfirm()
    setSaving(false)
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={() => setOpen(false)} open={open}>
      <DialogTitle className="flex items-center">
        <WarningAmber className="mr-2" />
        {title}
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText>{message}</DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button className="mx-2" variant="text" onClick={handleCancel}>
          {t('cancel')}
        </Button>
        <LoadingButton loading={saving} variant="contained" onClick={handleConfirm}>
          {t('yes')}
        </LoadingButton>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

```
// in any component
export default function SomeTable() {
const [confirmDelete, setConfirmDelete] = useState(false)
const [something, setSomething] = useState(null)

// triggered by a button on table
function handleDelete(item) {
setConfirmDelete(true)
setSomething(item)
}
async function deleteSomething() {
// delete
}

return (
<>
{*
table
*}

  <Confirm
    open={confirmDelete}
    setOpen={setConfirmDelete}
    title="are-you-sure"
    message="delete-confirm-message"
    onConfirm={deleteSomething}
  />
</>
);
}
```

I dont want to add the Confirm component to every other component like this.

Instead I want this:

```
// useDialog.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import Confirm from "../components/common/Confirm";

export default function useConfirm() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return {
    confirm: ({ title, message, onConfirm, onCancel = () => null }) =>
      createPortal(
        <Confirm
          open={open}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          title={title}
          message={message}
          onConfirm={onConfirm}
          onCancel={onCancel}
        />,
        document.getElementById("root")
      )
  };
}
```

```
// any component
import useConfirm from "./hooks/useConfirm";
import "./styles.css";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const { confirm } = useConfirm();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
          confirm({
            title: "Modal Title",
            message: "Modal Message",
            onConfirm: () => null
          })
        }
      >
        Open Confirm Modal
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I do it like this, createPortal is not doing anything, not throwing any errors either.
Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-saha-hjvgwz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Generally speaking, custom hooks (like useDialog) are meant to manage stateful logic and not directly handle rendering.

I suggest you render the Dialog in the root of your app. and use a general state management or contextAPI to control the modal open/close action as well as the title, message, ...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed @ArsanyBenyamine's comment and got it to working by converting it to context. I added Confirm component globally and controlled its state in in the context. Here is the final sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/modest-saha-hjvgwz

Comment: Stack Overflow recommends to *quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them*. Please post the relevant code from codesandbox directly into your answer. See the Stack Overflow help page [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

please update your `useDialog.js` file with below code. I hope it will work.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import Confirm from "../components/common/Confirm";

export default function useConfirm() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

  return {
    confirm: ({ title, message, onConfirm, onCancel = () => null}) =>
      {
        return (
          root.render(createPortal(
            <Confirm
              open={open}
              setOpen={setOpen}
              title={title}
              message={message}
              onConfirm={onConfirm}
              onCancel={onCancel}
            />,
            document.getElementById("root")
          ), document.createElement("div"))
        )
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: I already have root in my application so this throws an error. And the documentation says "When you want to render a piece of JSX in a different part of the DOM tree that isn’t a child of your component (for example, a modal or a tooltip), use createPortal instead of createRoot."  https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#caveats